# Thymeleaf throwing TemplateInputException and TemplateProcessingException intermittently

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot (2.1.0.RELEASE) webapp and am using Thymeleaf as the template engine.
In one page I get the following errors intermittently.
This error generally goes away if I restart my server or after a couple of hours.

```
2019-10-09 17:18:51.198 ERROR maa1n12-stg-004 --- [.1-6551-exec-51] o.s.b.w.s.s.ErrorPageFilter              : Cannot forward to error page for
 request [/testExecutionResponse/getResponseByExecutionId/8517] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have 
the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ib
m.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/testCaseR
esponse/showExecutionResult.html]")
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "executionSummary[i]" (template: "testCaseResponse/showExecutionResult" - line 133, col 49)

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "executionSummary[i]" (template: "testCaseResponse/showExecutionResult" - line 133, col 49)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate CompiledExpression
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelCompiler.compile(SpelCompiler.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: spel/Ex124, method: getValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/expression/EvaluationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Expecting to find integer on stack
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
```

The piece of code mentioned in the error is

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(executionSummary.size() - 1, 0, -1)}"
        th:with="summary=${executionSummary[i]}"
                th:classappend="${#strings.equals(summary.state,'SUCCESS')} ? 'alert alert-success' : 'alert alert-danger'">
                <td th:text="${summary.state}"></td>
                <td th:text="${summary.result}"></td>
                <td th:text="${summary.errorCategory}"></td>
                <td th:text="${summary.count}"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am unable to root cause the issue.

PS : Its not a memory issue as all the other components are working fine and the memory usage is around 15-20%

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If yes can you share to the community.

Comment: No. I am still stuck with this issue.